# optimize animation in cocos2d failed

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

When I didn't optimize animation,it worked well.But when I optimized my animation,the program crashed.And Xcode log said:

> Assertion failure in -[CCSpriteBatchNode addChild:z:tag:], /Users/hanpengbo/Documents/Xcode/cocos2d_helloWorld/cocos2d_helloWorld/libs/coco‌​s2d/CCSpriteBatchNode.m:183

in CCSpriteBatchNode.m:183,there is

```
NSAssert( child.texture.name == textureAtlas_.texture.name, @"CCSprite is not using the same texture id");
```

here is my code

```
// cache
    CCSpriteFrameCache *cache=[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
    [cache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"birdAtlas.plist"];

    // frame array
    NSMutableArray *framesArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
        NSString *frameName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bird%d.png", i];
        id frameObject=[cache spriteFrameByName:frameName];
        [framesArray addObject:frameObject];
    }

    // animation object
    id animObject=[CCAnimation animationWithFrames:framesArray delay:0.1];

    // animation action
    id animAction=[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animObject restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
    animAction=[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animAction];

    // sprite
    cocosGuy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"Icon.png"];//cocosGuy is CCSprite,declared earler
    cocosGuy.position = ccp( 200, 300 );

    // batchNode
    CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode=[CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"birdAtlas.png"];
    [self addChild:batchNode];
    [batchNode addChild:cocosGuy];

    [cocosGuy runAction:animAction];
```

UPDATE:
here is the corrected code,and it works well

```
    // batchNode
    CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode=[CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"birdAtlas.png"];
    [cocosGuy setTexture:[batchNode texture]];
    [self addChild:batchNode];
    [batchNode addChild:cocosGuy];
```

Comment: BatchNode has several requirements. Common causes of crash includes: inited, calling batchnode in a thread, or batchnode texture is already recycled. In your case you might want to keep a reference of `batchNode` somewhere, as a instance variable maybe. Do not let it destroy.

Comment: enable global exception breakpoint in Xcode, this will show you the line of the crash which helps to determine the issue (copy-paste the failed assert line here). Most importantly check that all animation frames are in the birdAtlas.png and not in a different texture atlas.

Comment: *** Assertion failure in -[CCSpriteBatchNode addChild:z:tag:], /Users/hanpengbo/Documents/Xcode/cocos2d_helloWorld/cocos2d_helloWorld/libs/cocos2d/CCSpriteBatchNode.m:183

Comment: NSAssert( child.texture.name == textureAtlas_.texture.name, @"CCSprite is not using the same texture id");

Comment: Thank you,I solved this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, your Icon.png texture should be in the birdAtlas.png texture, with appropriate declaration in the .plist. Batchnodes 1) are created with one texture (and only one), and 2) only accept as children sprites that are from the SAME texture.

... and , i dont know your intent, but typically you would have

```
CCSprite *cocosGuy = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"bird1.png"];
```

in that case, i think the batch node add will work.

... and , not sure using a batch node will be of any consequence for an animation, if the texture only contains the animation frames for that one animation. Frames are displayed one at a time, so i dont think you will benefit from the batched draw call.

Comment: “Icon.png texture should be in the birdAtlas.png texture”。Sorry,I don't understand what that mean.What is texture?

Comment: texture is basically a graphic content (like a png). An atlas is a texture that contains several images. Your birdAtlas probably has all the 10 images needed for the animation. Atlases can also be used to group multiple images in a single texture. Just remember that when using a batch node, all the children added to the batch node MUST come from the same texture (usually a .png file or some other graphic format), and the batch node MUST have been created with the same texture.